# After new partition gets created insert partition info in another table through trigger

Tags: oracle, datatrigger

I want to insert a record in `tbl_partition_info` through trigger when new partition gets created of table `tbl_payload_info`. I mean want to write a trigger to insert a record in `tbl_partition_info` table after new partition of `tbl_payload_info` table gets created.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with DDL Trigers.
Check out [this link](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2012/09/08/ddl-triggers/)

One important note from the author you should consider

> adding a partition is not DDL if Oracle decides to do it internally,
>   it’s only DDL if it’s an end-user statement

Implicit partition creation is a new feature of 11g and it reffers to the interval partition option.